# RxJs - Cancel all child events on Click(Navigation to another tab)

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am getting all the designs(lets say 100) from database and looping them.

I am loading each design image using child call

```
    <div *ngFor="let design of designs">
      <div (click)="showDesignDetails(design.designId)">
          <app-thumbnail [designId]="design.designId"></app-thumbnail>          
      </div>
    </div>
```

and in the child component my code looks like this.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.designService.getDesignById(this.designId).subscribe(
  design => {
    this.designLoaded = true;        
  },
  error => (this.errorMessage = error)
);
}
```

Obviously, each design image(100 calls) is taking time. In the meantime, If I want to navigate, I want to cancel all those calls.

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't make 100 calls, you should only make a single call and get all the required designs in a single call to the back end. Making 100 round trips to the server for a single page is horrible design and will cause your app to fail under load.

Comment: so, how do you load more than 1000 images which takes more than 2 minutes and with scroll bar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good pattern for cleaning up hot observables.

```
private destroy$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  this.designService.getDesignById(this.designId)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe(
    design => {
      this.designLoaded = true;        
    },
    error => (this.errorMessage = error)
  );
}


ngOnDestroy() {
   this.destroy$.next();
   this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

**Edit for question:**

The `ngOnDestroy` method is called when a page is navigated away from.  Its one of [Angular's Component Lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#component-lifecycle-hooks-overview) just like `ngOnInit` you are hooking into.

Your component will need to implement the following(at least) now:
`implements OnInit, OnDestroy`

Comment: Can you please explain how destroy gets called when I navigate to another page ?